# Assign domain name through CLI - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-api-tools

By EC2-API tools we can create new instance and assign an elastic ip to it through command line interface.
Is there any method to register a domain and map it with the elastic ip of the newly created instance through CLI  ?

Comment: This is confusing. Do you need to register a new domain or do you need to create a new DNS record pointing to the IP?

Comment: Register a new domain and then map to the ip.Or we can register the domain in advance , but need to map the new elastic ip with the domain name by CLI than doing it manually.